# How can I know if a contact opened my email

Tags: email

When I send an email Campaign I see that the Activity record that records the email sent is added but in the HTML Email Status there is nothing.
I have seen that for the Email Status list there are columns capturing if the email was opened.
How can I know if my email was opened?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sightly confused about the exact situation that you are seeing here - when you say 'in the HTML Email Status' there is nothing, are you referring to the HTML Email Status report?

If so, this report only returns records for the user that sent the HTML Email messages - even if you are the system administrator, if you didn't send the emails you won't see any results.

There's more details and a couple of potential workarounds in the following knowledge article:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003665&language=en_US

If this is the HTML Email Status related list, have you turned on email tracking for activities via the Setup -> App Setup -> Customize -> Activities -> Activity Settings -> Enable Email Tracking checkbox?  If so, check that this was turned on before you sent the emails that you want to track - it doesn't apply retrospectively.

Comment: I'm looking at the HTML Email Status list in my Contact's detail page. I was the one to send the email but it was captured in the Activity List and not the HTML Email Status list

Comment: I've updated the answer for the related list - is that any help?

Comment: In one of my orgs its your first comment that probably addresses my issue. Now I have to figure out how to create a report that shows Email Status from different users. From What I've read in you link that's not possible.                 In a second dev org I'm using I cannot even see my Email Status and the Activity setting is enabled

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you want great information about Contacts behavior related to Content you send  them, you can use Content Deliveries. Under App Setup / Customize / Content Deliveries, check "Enable Content Deliveries", then add the "Content Deliveries" related list to your Contact page layout. Then from the Contact page, click "New Content Delivery", select existing Content, or upload from your desktop. You have a lot of options, but I like to get an email alert when the Contact first clicks on the Content. You do need to copy and paste the URL that is generated and return and paste it into the email (I've been posting on the Ideas site for years about this - there should be a "Send Email" button on the page where the URL is generated, but it hasn't been improved). You get great details about your Contacts behavior related to the Content Delivery. Give it a try.

Comment: Can this be used in mass emails or only one by one?